# Camel TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy and the endpoint which timed out

Tags: apache-camel

We are doing a request reply pattern with aggregation where camel routes a message from one endpoint to many other endpoints; Camel aggregates the replies back and sends them to the original sender.

We are using the `TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy` and capturing a timeout in the callback to the `timeout` method.

The timeout method takes in `Exchange oldExchange, int index, int total, long timeout`. However, I am not able to find out the name or the URL of the endpoint which timed out.

I imagine that the index can be used to get the endpoint that timed out but I am not able to find out how to get it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you set it on a property before the request-reply? Exchange properties will persist on the exchange.

Comment: Thanks @vikingsteve. Sure, we can set the original list of recipients as a header value and then have some logic to find out who replied. I keep thinking that there is an easier solution since the index is in the method's signature. I am trying to find out what is the index referring to?